# React Native xCode huge build time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, build

Every build of my project require at least 20 minutes on iOS and 4 minutes on Android.
Searching on internet is not so normal.

I have a MacBook Air 1,6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 8 GB RAM and SSD.

This is the build with timing:
[image]

and this is my package.json dependencies:

```
"@alessiocancian/react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.11",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.2",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.4.6",
"@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^11.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/storage": "^11.4.1",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.3",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.15.0",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.0-next.18",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.0-next.13",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.0-next.25",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
"i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
"qs": "^6.10.1",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.2",
"react-native-actions-sheet": "^0.4.2",
"react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
"react-native-bootsplash": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-calendars": "^1.1255.0",
"react-native-date-picker": "^3.2.10",
"react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.4",
"react-native-fbsdk-next": "^4.3.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.1",
"react-native-image-picker": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
"react-native-localize": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-maps": "^0.28.0",
"react-native-modal": "^11.10.0",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.2.0",
"react-native-modal-selector": "2.0.3",
"react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
"react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
"react-native-progress-steps": "^1.3.4",
"react-native-push-notification": "^7.3.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.1.0",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
"react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
"tipsi-stripe": "^9.0.0"
```

What can I do to reduce the xCode build time?
I already tried everything on internet, but maybe there is some kind of misconfiguration/bug.

What do you suggest to check or change?

Comment: Are you about debug or release build?

Comment: Both are taking very long time

Comment: Basically idea behind react native that you don't need to build app at all. Unless first time, and releasing to the App Store.  But if you will keep rebuilding ReactNative "engine" - especially clean build, then it's more or less expected and know issue. With Xcode 13 and Swift5.5 it should be better.

Comment: I'd expected a faster or equal build time in iOS than Android, but 5 times minutes more than Android is really too much. It let me think that is not a framework problem, but some misconfiguration. Am I wrong?

Comment: I have similar building (release) time. It's normal for ios. For better time building do not clean project before start build.